# Trying to run android studio won’t open

Tags: java, windows

I’m trying to run android studio but it gives me this :

`Error launching android studio`

```
Failed to load JVM DLL C:\ProgramFiles\Java\jdk-10.0.2\bin\server\jvm.dll
If you already have a 32-bit JDK install, define a JAVA_HOME variable in
computer > system properties > system setting > environment variables
```

... I have downloaded java from oracle (they didn’t have a 32bit version only 64bit ) it said it was installed successfully but then when I try to run android it didn’t work ...
I went into the environment variables and try to add java_home and put the folder link and it’s still not working ...
I’m so at lost here , I would really appreciate it if you guys can help me out ( as it’s my first time trying to learn how to code )
Thank you so much for your time and expertise

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because diagnosing it would require full details on the version of Android Studio that OP is trying to install, the OS, previous possibly-conflicting installs, machine hardware, and so on. Yes, Android Studio is a programming tool -- but this seems like a shortcoming in the installer. Programming is not yet even remotely involved.

Comment: Is your machine 32 bit or 64 bit? What is your operating system, and is it 32 or 64-bit? Which version of AS have you downloaded? Have you followed all instructions in their installation page, and googled the error? You may have downloaded a 32-bit AS and tried to run it with a 64-bit JDK...

Comment: download a 64bit and running on a 64bit system too and i did follow the instruction and google the errors to but it only lead me to something else ... sorry to bothered you

Answer (score 0):

Long time ago I didn't go to Windows but in my memories you have to specify the Java_Home path and also add it to the path. Did you do that ?

(Sory if it's not that or if that don't solve the problem)

Comment: I downloaded it but I wasn’t even in my environment variables so I add it myself and also in the paths but I used the bin folder .. maybe I should just use the JDK folder instead ?

Answer (score 0):

You should set `Path` and `JAVA_HOME` In Your System

**1.JAVA_HOME**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

**2.ANDROID_SDK_HOME**

[image]

**3.PATH**

```
F:\dev_two\jdk\jdk1.8.0_101\bin;F:\dev_two\sdk\platform-tools
```

[image]

[image]

[image]